# SQL query to get table rows whose columns should not match with other table columns

Tags: sql

Thanks in advance,

Actually I have two tables carts and checks. Carts table contains rows as below

```
id |username  |orderid  | exam_name | price
1  |  Rajesh  | ABC123  |   PMP     |  $60
2  |  Rajesh  | ABC123  |   CPM     |  $70
3  |  David   | ABC789  |  ITIL     |   $80
```

`checks` table contains rows as below

```
id |username |order_id | exam      |  price
1    Rajesh  | ABC123  |   PMP     |  $60
2    Rajesh  | ABC123  |   CPM     |  $70
```

I need a row data of carts table whose orderid column and exam_name column should not match with checks table order_id column and exam column

Something like this as below:

```
id |username  |orderid  | exam_name | price
1  |  David   | ABC789  |  ITIL     |   $80
```

Comment: `SELECT * FROM Carts ca LEFT OUTER JOIN Checks ch on ca.orderid <> ch.orderid and ca.exam_name <> ch.exam`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One method is `not exists`:

```
select c.*
from carts c
where not exists (select 1
                  from checks ch
                  where ch.orderid = c.orderid and ch.exam_name = c.exam_name
                 );
```

A similar method is `left join`:

```
select c.*
from carts c left join
     checks ch
     on ch.orderid = c.orderid and ch.exam_name = c.exam_name
where ch.orderid is null;
```

And in some databases you can use `not in`:

```
select c.*
from carts c
where (c.orderid, c.exam_name) not in (select ch.orderid, ch.exam_name from checks ch);
```

Comment: The last query is working fine . Thank you very much for your help

Answer (score 2):

```
select c.*
from carts c
left join checks ch on c.id = ch.id
where ch.id is null;
```

Hope this should solve your problem.

Comment: Instead of using id if i use orderid then it is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *
from Carts 
where  exam_name  not in (select  exam       from checks) 
and id  not in (select id  from  checks)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM Carts 
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM checks 
    WHERE checks.OrderId = Carts.OrderId 
    and Carts.exam_name = checks.exam_name)
```